# How to pass traits as arguments for a templated struct?

Tags: c++, templates, struct, arguments, type-traits

Say I have something like this

```
template<typename T1, typename T2>
struct my_struct
{
    using type = typename T1<T2>::type;
};
```

In the main function I want to be able to write `using test = typename my_struct<remove_const_t<>, const float>::type;` where test will be equal to float since `remove_const_t<const float>` returns float.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a [template template parameter](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters#Template_template_parameter) so you can pass the template to `my_struct`.  That would look like

```
template<template<typename> typename T1, typename T2>
struct my_struct
{
    using type = typename T1<T2>::type;
};
```

and then you would use it like

```
using test = typename my_struct<is_integral, float>::type;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need template template parameter.

Syntax would be:

```
template<template <typename> class C, typename T>
struct my_struct
{
    using type = typename C<T>::type;
};
```